# Как получить адрес клиента?

Tags: c++, сокет, http, winsock

Пытаюсь делать по [этой](https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-http-server-over-sockets/) статье, перекопал гугл, но ничего толкового не нашел (или просто ещё не знаю, как правильно формулировать запросы по этой теме)

Как можно получить ip адрес подключаемого клиента?

Вот скопированный код из статьи:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

// Для корректной работы freeaddrinfo в MinGW
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

// Необходимо, чтобы линковка происходила с DLL-библиотекой
// Для работы с сокетам
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

using std::cerr;

int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData; // служебная структура для хранение информации
                     // о реализации Windows Sockets
                     // старт использования библиотеки сокетов процессом
                     // (подгружается Ws2_32.dll)
    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    // Если произошла ошибка подгрузки библиотеки
    if(result != 0) {
        cerr << "WSAStartup failed: " << result << "\n";
        return result;
    }

    struct addrinfo* addr = NULL; // структура, хранящая информацию
                                  // об IP-адресе  слущающего сокета

                                  // Шаблон для инициализации структуры адреса
    struct addrinfo hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));

    hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // AF_INET определяет, что будет
                               // использоваться сеть для работы с сокетом
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // Задаем потоковый тип сокета
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP; // Используем протокол TCP
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // Сокет будет биндиться на адрес,
                                 // чтобы принимать входящие соединения

                                 // Инициализируем структуру, хранящую адрес сокета - addr
                                 // Наш HTTP-сервер будет висеть на 8000-м порту локалхоста
    result = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "8000", &hints, &addr);

    // Если инициализация структуры адреса завершилась с ошибкой,
    // выведем сообщением об этом и завершим выполнение программы
    if(result != 0) {
        cerr << "getaddrinfo failed: " << result << "\n";
        WSACleanup(); // выгрузка библиотеки Ws2_32.dll
        return 1;
    }

    // Создание сокета
    int listen_socket = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype,
                               addr->ai_protocol);
    // Если создание сокета завершилось с ошибкой, выводим сообщение,
    // освобождаем память, выделенную под структуру addr,
    // выгружаем dll-библиотеку и закрываем программу
    if(listen_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cerr << "Error at socket: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        freeaddrinfo(addr);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Привязываем сокет к IP-адресу
    result = bind(listen_socket, addr->ai_addr, (int)addr->ai_addrlen);

    // Если привязать адрес к сокету не удалось, то выводим сообщение
    // об ошибке, освобождаем память, выделенную под структуру addr.
    // и закрываем открытый сокет.
    // Выгружаем DLL-библиотеку из памяти и закрываем программу.
    if(result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cerr << "bind failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        freeaddrinfo(addr);
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Инициализируем слушающий сокет
    if(listen(listen_socket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cerr << "listen failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        closesocket(listen_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    const int max_client_buffer_size = 1024;
    char buf[max_client_buffer_size];
    int client_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    for(;;) {
        // Принимаем входящие соединения
        client_socket = accept(listen_socket, NULL, NULL);
        if(client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            cerr << "accept failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
            closesocket(listen_socket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        result = recv(client_socket, buf, max_client_buffer_size, 0);

        std::stringstream response; // сюда будет записываться ответ клиенту
        std::stringstream response_body; // тело ответа

        if(result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            // ошибка получения данных
            cerr << "recv failed: " << result << "\n";
            closesocket(client_socket);
        } else if(result == 0) {
            // соединение закрыто клиентом
            cerr << "connection closed...\n";
        } else if(result > 0) {
            // Мы знаем фактический размер полученных данных, поэтому ставим метку конца строки
            // В буфере запроса.
            buf[result] = '\0';

            // Данные успешно получены
            // формируем тело ответа (HTML)
            response_body << "<title>Test C++ HTTP Server</title>\n"
                << "<h1>Test page</h1>\n"
                << "<p>This is body of the test page...</p>\n"
                << "<h2>Request headers</h2>\n"
                << "<pre>" << buf << "</pre>\n"
                << "<em><small>Test C++ Http Server</small></em>\n";

            // Формируем весь ответ вместе с заголовками
            response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                << "Version: HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
                << "Content-Length: " << response_body.str().length()
                << "\r\n\r\n"
                << response_body.str();

            // Отправляем ответ клиенту с помощью функции send
            result = send(client_socket, response.str().c_str(),
                          response.str().length(), 0);

            if(result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                // произошла ошибка при отправле данных
                cerr << "send failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
            }
            // Закрываем соединение к клиентом
            closesocket(client_socket);
        }
    }

    // Убираем за собой
    closesocket(listen_socket);
    freeaddrinfo(addr);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Находите функцию accept. Эта функция используется для принятия запроса от клиента на установление соединения с сервером. В Вашем примере второй и третий параметры равны NULL. А именно их необходимо использовать для принятия данных о клиентe.

```
sockaddr_in cs_addr; //или SOCKADDR_IN cs_addr;
socklen_t cs_addrsize = sizeof (cs_addr); //или int cs_addrsize = sizeof(cs_addr);
client_socket = accept(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &cs_addr, &cs_addrsize);
```

В `cs_addr.sin_addr` будет храниться ip-адрес клиента. К строке приводится при помощи `inet_ntoa`.

Comment: Спасибо, это работает.

Comment: Раз вы разбираетесь, хотел бы ещё совета спросить. Если я собираюсь обрабатывать клиентов в потоках, я правильно понимаю, что после accept я буду создавать поток? Отправляя в него копию client_socket, и далее весь код, что ниже по циклу, будет обрабатываться уже потоком

Comment: @Fangog добудьте себе книгу Снейдера http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/126048/ - многие вопросы отпадут.

Comment: @Fangog Да. Вы понимаете правильно, если собираетесь обрабатывать клиентов в потоках. Но учтите, что создание потоков достаточно трудоемкая операция (да и переключение между ними тоже не бесплатное) с точки зрения ресурсов. Поэтому создание для каждого клиента отдельного потока - вопрос целесообразности. При каких-то тестах, при малом количестве клиентов, при низкой загрузке такой подход может быть оправдан в целях упрощения читаемости и понимания кода. Но если делать что-либо серьезное, то такой подход будет неверен.

Comment: Иногда (где-то в глубине вызовов от `accept()` (или даже уже в другом процессе, который никак (кроме унаследованного дескриптора) с ним не связан)) может пригодиться `int getpeername(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);` (надеюсь, в винде она тоже есть).

Comment: А какой подход правильней? Я хотел сделать ограниченное кол-во потоков, и если приходит новое соединение то отправлять его в очередь, в менее загруженный поток (P.S. ох, ещё одна книга, которую придется читать)

Comment: @Fangog Рекомендованная книга описывает начальные вопросы работы с сокетами, работу сети, адресацию, какие вопросы могут возникнуть при обрывах, реконектах и как их решать. Но она не касается архитектуры сетевого приложения и использования более актуальных API (epoll, iocp и т.д.). Поэтому я бы сказал, что прочитать ее нужно (и даже уже более менее опытным разработчикам из нее будет что почерпнуть). Но чтобы вот так в срачном порядке и от корки до корки - не думаю, что обязательно.

Comment: @Fangog Тот подход, который Вы описали в последнем своем комментарии, выглядит более правильным, чем создавать отдельный поток для каждого подключения (как описывали ранее). При таком подходе единственное, что кажется лишним, это попытка балансировки по загруженности потока. Как ее определить - еще тот вопрос. Ведь бОльшее количество подключений в потоке абсолютно не означает, что он выполняет больше работы (может подключения простаивают). Поэтому подключения просто раскидываются по порядку и равномерно. А загрузкой и распределением потоков по ядрам процессора уже займется система.

Comment: @Fangog Но основной недостаток приведенного выше кода, который не решается Вашим подходом, это когда Вы опрашиваете клиентский сокет (функция recv), то блокируете весь поток, пока не придут от клиента данные. Избавиться от этого недостатка можно переведя сокеты в неблокирущий режим. Но тогда, для определения поступления данных от клиента, нужно дописывать соответственно код. "Плюсом" еще к этому недостатку является постоянная проверка всех клиентских сокетов в цикле. Это решается использованием или iocp под вин, или epoll под лин.

Comment: А есть кроссплатформенные библиотеки для работы с сокетами? Я бы хотел, чтобы сервер в конце-концов запускался под линукс, но писать мне удобней на винде

Comment: @Fangog Да. Есть boost::asio, poco::net. Но все зависит от того, как Вы все-таки собираетесь реализовывать сервер. Если не будете использовать iocp или epoll (а для клиента они не нужны, только для сервера), а обойдетесь только указанным выше кодом, то смысла использовать другие библиотеки нет. Этот код, с незначительными правками, будет компилироваться и под win и под linux. В выше упомянутой книге, насколько мне помнится, описываются ньюансы различий при использовании, но с бОльшего, для linux там только другие header файлы подключатся и не нужна dll-ка с инициализацией WSA.